# Read and write data.frames in the correct way

Tags: java, r, twitter, read.table, write.table

my problem is very simple, I have a file which contains plenty of tweet one per row not surrounded by quotes. After reading the file I created "dataset", to randomize it and to eliminate duplicates:

```
dataset <- read.table(file, header=FALSE, sep="\n", stringsAsFactors=F)
unique_ds <- unique.data.frame(dataset)
random_ds <- unique_ds[sample(nrow(unique_ds)),]
write.table(data.frame(random_ds),file="tweets_final.txt", sep="\n", quote=F, col.names=F, row.names=F)
```

*random_ds* has **2246** rows. But when I open my file I've just created, I see **more than 5000 rows**.

**First question:** I just can't understand **where** is the problem. Is it maybe in write.table or the code above?

[consider that in each tweet in the original file, I've removed newline and carriage return; Java code below]

```
out = out.replaceAll("[\n\r]", " ");
```

**Second question:** suppose to add per each row a new variable (for examples a category for the tweet), when I will read it back in R, like a csv file is this format appropriate: *"my tweet",type* with the code below?

```
ds <- read.csv(file = "tweet_classified.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "\"")
```

In particular how could I manage in Java/R the problem of quotes inside quotes?

thanks

**Important** I've just consider the fact that obviously, twitter data contain # character, so I would ask another question: is it possibile that sobsitute hashtags with \n? or just considers it as comment, and throws away tha part following #

Comment: Do you need `tweet_classified.txt` to be portable between java and R once you have begun manipulating it in R? Specifically, once you `write.table()` do you need to read that data back into a different stack or will you only be working with it in R henceforth?

Comment: Why do you have `sep="\n"` in `write.table()`?  That's putting a newline in the file between each column in the data.frame you are writing.

Comment: I would manipulate data in Java, and back again read them with R

Comment: @devmacrile may well have it. Worse yet, you may well have multiple `\n` inserted. `sep 
the field separator string. Values within each row of x are separated by this string.`

Comment: @ShawnMehan Because of this problem: _Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'_ when I'm using `random_ds <- unique_ds[sample(unique_ds,nrow(unique_ds)),]`

Comment: Right. I think that there's a bigger rock under the surface here with your approach. But I do think that you should replace `\n` with something like `:` in your `write.table()` and see what happens.

Comment: @devmacrile I would ask you what kind of separator I have to use, in order to read the entire row, without break the in some part of it.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your original `file`, or better yet upload it somewhere and post a link??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved the problem with substituting  `read.table` with `gsub("\"","'",readLines(con))`.
When I'm writing to file I'm going to use `quote=T`

here's mycode:

```
file_list <- list.files()

for (file in file_list){
   con <- file(file)

   if (!exists("dataset")){
      dataset <- data.frame(gsub("\"","'",readLines(con)),stringsAsFactors = F)
   }

   if (exists("dataset")){
      temp_dataset <- data.frame(gsub("\"","'",readLines(con)),stringsAsFactors = F)
      dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
      rm(temp_dataset)


    }
  close.connection(con)
}

unique_ds <- unique.data.frame(dataset)
random_ds <- unique_ds[sample(nrow(unique_ds)),]
write.table(data.frame(random_ds, stringsAsFactors = F),file="unclassified.txt",col.names = F, row.names = F, quote = T)
```

Then in reading phase:

```
dataset <- read.csv(file="unclassified.txt", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,quote="\"")
```